# How to run countdown timer functionality in the background even the app is killed in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, countdowntimer, background-task

I am new in flutter. I am making a countdown timer app in flutter. The next thing I need to know that "How I can run my selected Countdown time in the background?" I had done this functionality in native android Kotlin, but I need to get this task done in flutter.

Any suggestion for this functionality in flutter?

I had used timer.periodic but when I close my app the time starts from the given time.
It should be to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you implement it in native android, you can not run `Dart` code to run in the background until you contact the native features, you need a work manager package for this, like :

https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager